# Spring Data Containing doesn't work for Integer

Tags: java, spring-data

I am implementing search method. And i want to searach for integers. 
So i have this method in repo:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
      List<Car> findByRocznikIsContaining(Integer rocznik);
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
    public class Car {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String model;
private @Lob
String historiaSamochodu;
private Double przebieg;
private Integer rocznik;
```

But when i pass to my method any integer e.g.:

```
findByRocznikIsContaining(5);
```

It throws an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [%5%] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
```

Any idea why?

Comment: %5% suggests the 5 is interpretated as a String in the query. Can we see the implementation of your findByRocznikIsContaining method?

Comment: @Jorge.V it's Spring Data, so it is implementing "auto magically" :) I can't show it to you. 
I tried to pass a String, but doesn't help, bcs i got similar error to this, that is expecting Integer not a String.

Comment: Doubt it will work, can you try to pass "new Integer(5)" as parameter?

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: Upvoting and fav'ing, I'm curious too. While (hopefully) someone else answers, can you try changing your parameter from Integer to Long? It may be searching using the @Id'd attribute since it is all "auto-magical", and complaining coz it expects Long and you are passing Integer.

Comment: nah it should search for only "rocznik" field, i tried to make simple:
findByRocznik(Integer rocznik); and it works. And another simple method with Like: findByRocznikLike(Integer rocznik)  works too. But i need to get it work with "Containing" which for String fields works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked this link https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation and for `findBy...Containing` it shows the following pseudo SQL code `… where x.firstname like ?1 (parameter bound wrapped in %)`. Which in your case is transformed in `where x.roczik like %5%`. And basically `%5%` is a String and cannot be converted to Integer.
You could try to go with `@Query` annotation for that method like this:

```
@Query("select c from Car c where to_char(c.rocznik) like %?1%")
List<Car> findByRocznikIsContaining(Integer rocznik);
```

Comment: Yeah, i tried that and it doesn't work. 
But i already know why, SQL doesn't support 'LIKE' for Integers. 
I did it with criteria where i could map Integer to String and it worked.

Comment: @Moler how did you do it using criteria?

Comment: Never mind. I figured it out. 

    predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("id").as(String.class), "%" + request.getId() + "%"));